# Python, weird output for strftime

Tags: python

I created a simple datetime object as

```
start = datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 15, 10, 0, 0)
```

Now, on printing start I get

```
datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 15, 10, 0)
```

But when I do

```
start.strftime('%I.%m%p')
```

I get output as

```
'10.07AM'
```

I do not why the there is added 7 minutes. Can anyone point as to what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%m` formats the *month*, not the minutes. Use `%M` for minutes:

```
>>> start = datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 15, 10, 0, 0)
>>> start.strftime('%I.%M%p')
'10.00AM'
>>> start.replace(minute=42).strftime('%I.%M%p')
'10.42AM'
```

Answer (score 1):

It was something really silly, it should have been **%M and not %m**